# Moving the Color Trim to Quick Control Screen

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-ii, camera-controls

I just got a Canon 5D Mark II, and I am trying to get the settings so that the color trim is in the Quick Control Screen.

Does anyone know how to get this there?

Comment: I can find no reference to 'color trim' in the manual or even with a cursory Google. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the contents of the Quick Control Screen can't be customised.

I assume by colour trim you mean the `WB SHIFT/BKT` menu option? The Quick Control Screen will show a `WM +/-` icon when this is option is adjusted away from 0, but you can't access the setting from that screen.

[image: 5D mkII Quick Control Screen]

If you need convenient access to this setting, I think think the only option would be to make use of the `My Menu` screen. (in the camera menu it's the one on the far right with a star as it's icon)
You could add the `WB SHIFT/BKT` option to this screen along with all the other options that you need quick access to (up to 6), then set the `My Menu` screen to display first when you press the `MENU` button. (this is done via `My Menu settings` > `Display from My Menu` > `Enable`)

[image: 5DmkII My Menu screen]
*Image of My Menu screen*